# Formatting Text Files Generated by PHP

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I'm building a super simple PHP CMS, and have a question about formatting text...

I'm storing my news files in .txt files (should be SQL, I know), and would like to know how to format the text that gets saved in the text file. This is the code that stores the lines that I want to format:

```
$newsTitle = isset($_POST["title"]) ? $_POST["title"] : "Untitled";
$submitDate = date("m/d/y g:iA");
```

I want to wrap the first line in an `<h2>` and the second line in an `<h3>`, but I have no idea how. I tried just wrapping the `m/d/y g:iA` bit in the second line with a `<h3>` but that generated some really weird code in the .txt file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newsTitle = isset($_POST["title"]) ? $_POST["title"] : "Untitled";
$submitDate = date("m/d/y g:iA");
$saveString = "<h2>$newsTitle</h2>\n<h3>$submitDate</h3>";
file_put_contents("filename.txt",$saveString);
```

Read up a little on [php strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and how you can use variables with them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$newsTitle = isset($_POST["title"]) ? "<h2>".$_POST["title"]."</h2>" : "Untitled";
$submitDate = "<h3>".date("m/d/y g:iA")."</h3>";
```